# Terraform zip unique json file per one zip file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a folder e.g. policies with multiple .yaml file in it and I'm trying to convert it to .json and move it to ./src folder and zip it so each .json should be unique to 1 zip file but currently when I applied my terraform it always just get the last .json file for all zip instead I want:

zip1 has first.json (from first.yaml)
zip2 has second.json (from second.yaml)

so it seems the archive file is not looping together with the json conversion but instead, only archive once that function is over. Please help thanks, appreciate any help or suggestions

```
# Loop through each policy file and create a data source
data "local_file" "policy" {
  for_each = local.policy_files
  filename = "${path.module}/policies/${each.value}"
}

# Loop through each policy file and use a template to convert the yaml to json
data "template_file" "policy_json" {
  for_each = local.policy_files
  template = jsonencode(yamldecode(data.local_file.policy[each.key].content))
}

# Loop through each policy file and extract the rendered template content
locals {
  policy_json_content = {for k, v in data.template_file.policy_json : k => v.rendered}
}

# Loop through each policy file and write the json output to a temporary file
resource "local_file" "temp_config" {
  for_each = local.policy_files
  content  = local.policy_json_content[each.key]
  filename = "${path.module}/temp_config_${each.key}.json"
}

# Loop through each policy file and move the temporary config.json to the src folder
resource "null_resource" "move_to_src" {
  for_each = local.policy_files
  triggers = {
    config_content = local_file.temp_config[each.key].content
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      mv ${path.module}/temp_config_${each.key}.json ../../src/config.json
    EOT
  }

}


# working fine
# Create a zip archive of the folder
data "archive_file" "policy_zip" {
  for_each = { for idx, policy_data in local.all_policy_data : idx => policy_data }

  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.module}/${local.folder_name}"
  output_path = "${path.module}/${local.folder_name}_${each.value.policies[0].name}.zip"

  depends_on = [ null_resource.move_to_src ]
}

# Upload the function source code zip file to the bucket
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "function_zip" {
  for_each = { for idx, policy_data in local.all_policy_data : idx => policy_data }

  name   = "${each.value.policies[0].name}-${random_string.suffix.result}"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.cloud_custodian_bucket[each.key].name
  source = data.archive_file.policy_zip[each.key].output_path

  depends_on = [
    data.archive_file.policy_zip
  ]
}
```